# How to copy animation from 1 armature to another with same bone names, same hierarchy, but not the same size and position

Tags: animation

I have 2 armatures A and B and I already made some animations in A.

And now I have B, which has the same bones hierarchy, and naming, with A.
But each bone in B does not have the same size, and initial position and rotation, with A.
(eg. I duplicate A as B. then in edit mode, I adjust the bones in B, like make the head bone larger, place the hip bone lower, etc.)

So how can I copy animation from A to B in Blender?

Thanks

PS. I am using 2.8+

Comment: B will act like A except the head and tail of each bone will be a different local place

Comment: @moonboots yes. This is what I mean. They have same structure and same bone naming. Except the head and tail of each bone will be a different local place. Thanks for your clarifying.